# Excel quick analysis logarithmic scale

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to apply the "Icon Set" Quick Analysis format to my data. But how do I configure what is considered a high value or low value?

In my worksheet I want:

- Values between 0 and 1 should be red.
- Values equal to 1 should be yellow.
- Values greater than 1 until infinity should be green.

I'm not sure, but I think this is a logarithmic scale.

Thanks.

[edit]

Sorry, I failed to understand that an icon set only has 3 states, as opposed to a smooth gradient. Can a gradient be set to a logarithmic scale instead?

Comment: with only 3 colours in total it's really different to understand why it would be a log scale. Could you please explain it / add some more examples?

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use `Conditional Formatting, Highlight Cells Rules`, and choose:
Between 0 and 1 and Fill Red
a second time =1 and Fill Yellow
a third time >1 and Fill Green

It will give you the correct color instead of gradient one
Another method is by setting the percentage according to your color, after using Icon Set in Conditional Formatting choose Manage Rules and modify like in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to have the colors/icons change based on a logarithmic scale instead of linear?

Comment: @posfan12, I was suprised that SuperSam figured out a way to answer your question because the question is really confusing.  You have rules for each color that relate to numerical values.  Those values are whatever they are.  Linear and logarithmic scales are irrelevant to the rules.  You can measure your height in inches or centimeters, but either way, you're the same height.  If you think the scale is somehow related, please expand your question to better explain what you're trying to do.  An example would be a big help.

Comment: I see what you mean. An icon set only has 3 states as opposed to a smooth gradient. Can a gradient be aligned with a logarithmic function instead?